# How to add a list in a list to another list

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I have a list called `test3` and I want to add this list to another list `test0`. The problem is that I only want the `"noequipment"` "sublist" to be added to the `test0`.

I tried it with the following code:

```
var test0 = test0 + test3["noequipment"];
```

This is list `test3`:

```
var test3 = [
  {
    "noequipment": [
      {"name": "test0.1", "time": 10},
      {"name": "test0.2", "time": 10},
      {"name": "test0.3", "time": 10},
      {"name": "test0.4", "time": 10},
    ]
  },
  {
    "equipment1": [
      {"name": "test1.1", "time": 10},
      {"name": "test1.2", "time": 10},
      {"name": "test1.3", "time": 10},
      {"name": "test1.4", "time": 10},
    ]
  },
];
```

Comment: `test0.add(test3["noequipment"])` ?

Comment: the "noequipment is still red underlined

Comment: what error is that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this answer

```
for (var i in test3[0]['noequipment']) {
  test0.add(i);
  print("===========>>${test0}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please test this code.**

```
 test0.addAll(test3[0]["noequipment"]);
```

Make sure parent list is defined as `var test0 = [] ;`

Here I test this code https://pastebin.pl/view/ff02c9cc

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but the "noquipment" is still red underlined, even though I have checked whether I have written it correctly or not

Comment: please check it now.   test0.addAll(test3[0]["noequipment"]);

Answer (score 0):

Use code below assuming `test0` is already an array

```
test0.addAll(test3[0]['noequipment'])
```